# Adding Google Earth linestrings to existing code

Tags: vba

Whilst fairly proficient with Excel, VBA makes my head spin. Please be patient with the newbies.

I have some existing code which parses data from an Excel spreadsheet and creates a KML file which plots placemarks on Google Earth. I would like to add linestrings joining these placemarks.

The code included a Public Function CreatePlacemark which I copied and created Public Function CreateLineString.
I then modified the existing Public Sub CreateKML() and tried to add the code to create the Linestring's.

```
    Public Function CreatePlacemark(PlaceName As String, Description As String, Longitude As Double, Latitude As Double) As String
  Dim Xml As String
  Xml = ""
  Xml = Xml & "  <Placemark>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <description>{DESCRIPTION}</description>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <name>{PLACE_NAME}</name>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <View>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "      <longitude>{LONGITUDE}</longitude>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "      <latitude>{LATITUDE}</latitude>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "      <range>{RANGE}</range>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "      <tilt>{TILT}</tilt>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "      <heading>{HEADING}</heading>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    </View>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <visibility>1</visibility>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <styleUrl>root://styleMaps#default?iconId=0x307</styleUrl>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <Style>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "      <icon></icon>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    </Style>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <Point>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "      <coordinates>{LONGITUDE},{LATITUDE}</coordinates>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    </Point>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "  </Placemark>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{PLACE_NAME}", CleanString(PlaceName))
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{DESCRIPTION}", CleanString(Description))
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{LONGITUDE}", Longitude)
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{LATITUDE}", Latitude)
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{RANGE}", 141.4)
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{TILT}", 0)
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{HEADING}", 0)
  CreatePlacemark = Xml
End Function
Public Function CreateLineString(PlaceName As String, Description As String, Longitude As Double, Latitude As Double) As String
  Dim Xml As String
  Xml = ""
  Xml = Xml & "  <Placemark>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <description>{DESCRIPTION}</description>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <name>{PLACE_NAME}</name>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <styleUrl>#yellowLine</styleUrl>"
  Xml = Xml & "    <LineString>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <extrude>0</extrude>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    <tessellate>1</tessellate>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "      <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "      <coordinates>{LONGITUDE},{LATITUDE}</coordinates>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "    </LineString>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "  </Placemark>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{PLACE_NAME}", CleanString(PlaceName))
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{DESCRIPTION}", CleanString(Description))
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{LONGITUDE}", Longitude)
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{LATITUDE}", Latitude)
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{RANGE}", 141.4)
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{TILT}", 0)
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{HEADING}", 0)
  CreateLineString = Xml
End Function
Public Sub CreateKML()
  Dim OutputPath As String, Filename As String
  Dim KMLName As String
  Dim PlaceName As String, Description As String
  Dim LineString As String
  Dim Longitude As Double, Latitude As Double
  Dim Xml As String
  Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim Rng As Excel.Range
  Dim Row As Long
  Dim Arr As Variant
  Dim f As Long
  Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KML")
  Set Rng = Sht.Range("CoordData")
  OutputPath = Sht.Range("OutputPath").Value
  KMLName = Sht.Range("KMLName").Value
  Arr = Rng.Value
  Row = 2
  Xml = ""
  Xml = Xml & "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "<Folder>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "  <name>{FOLDER_NAME}</name>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Xml & "  <open>1</open>" & vbCrLf
  Xml = Replace(Xml, "{FOLDER_NAME}", KMLName)
  Do While Arr(Row, 1) <> ""
    PlaceName = Arr(Row, 1)
    Description = ""
    Latitude = Arr(Row, 2)
    Longitude = Arr(Row, 3)
    Xml = Xml & CreatePlacemark(PlaceName, Description, Longitude, Latitude)
    Row = Row + 1
  Loop

  Do While Arr(Row, 1) <> ""
    PlaceName = Arr(Row, 1)
    Description = ""
    Latitude = Arr(Row, 2)
    Longitude = Arr(Row, 3)
  Xml = Xml & CreateLineString(PlaceName, Description, Longitude, Latitude)
    Row = Row + 1
  Loop



  Xml = Xml & "</Folder>" & vbCrLf
  Filename = OutputPath & "\" & KMLName & ".kml"
  On Error Resume Next
  Kill Filename
  On Error GoTo 0
  f = FreeFile
  Open Filename For Binary As #f
  Put #f, , Xml
  Close #f
  LaunchAssociatedFile Filename
End Sub
```

The code runs without any errors but only displays Placemarks but no LineStrings.

Comment: You do not reset `Row` variable before the second loop, so it is never executed, add `Row = 2` before second `Do While`.

Comment: There seems to be no loop? Only one coordinate is between the coordinates tags. <coordinates>121.4617,-30.78944</coordinates>  The generated KML file should be something like,
 <coordinates>
121.46166666667,-30.7894444444391,0
128.883333333302,-31.7166666666744,0
121.46166666667,-30.7894444444391,0
</coordinates>

Comment: The loop goes over the `<placemark>` tag. So for each row it should create the entire `<placemark>` node.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I don't understand what I need to change in the code. Sorry for being new to this but I still have trouble with syntax and order of code.

Comment: What needs to be changed in the second loop to return only <Stringline> . It should be something like this which includes <Placemark> as an opening statement. <Placemark> <name>Flight plan</name>  <description>Flight plan from Charter Enquiry</description>  <styleUrl>#yellowLine</styleUrl><LineString>
        <extrude>0</extrude> <tessellate>1</tessellate><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode> <coordinates>
          121.461666,-30.7894491,0
          128.883302,-31.7166744,0
          121.4616667,-30.789491,0
        </coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>